# .custom-file-input:lang(en) ~ .custom-file-label -> unmatched pseudo-class :lang

Tags: angular, aws-amplify

I got the following error message in my amplify project after running this command:

`npm install --save aws-amplify @aws-amplify/ui-angular`

Everything is working fine, and I can access my app on localhost:4200 but I just want to know what's causing the following error and how to resolve it please.

Warning: 1 rules skipped due to selector errors:

.custom-file-input:lang(en) ~ .custom-file-label -> unmatched pseudo-class :lang

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Drive by answer. I got this issue. Searched for it. Found this question with no answer. Posting a solution for the next person who drops by.

The line of code it is complaining about is in Bootstrap 4 (the bootstrap.css file).

Why would it be complaining? Something is running Bootstrap 5 and that (lang(en)) no longer works in Bootstrap 5.

How to fix it depends on how the issue comes up.

For me, I have a project with Angular, Bootstrap, and another dependency. I upgraded to Angular 12. The third dependency needed to be updated to work with Angular 12. Updating that pulls in Bootstrap 5. For me, the fix is to upgrade my project to Bootstrap 5.

Good luck any other souls who stumble upon this.